# Cant Deploy the Crystal Report Viewe Forms in Client Computers

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm new to VB.Net and I'm trying to develop a desktop app using VB.Net 2019 and Crystal reports. I have few questions which i need some clarifications.

My project is is working fine in my development machine.(VB.Net , MS SQL , Crystal Reports). But when trying to deploy it to clients, I get some errors when trying to load reports. I have installed CR13SP27MSI32_0-10010309 in development pc and CR13SP27MSI32_0-10010309 for clients.

I Have inserted and designed the Crystal Reports inside Visual studio IDE. So, when loading reports crystal report viewer, I do not use a report path in the code. I just declare a new instance of the existing report. Is this correct or do i always have to show the physical path of the report source?

I tried to to create a setup project but It fails during the build. So, I copied the exe to a client machine and I get a error when trying to load a form with a Crystal Report Viewer. Is it because the required files are missing from the client PC?. Do i have to install both Visual studio and Crystal report in client computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client machines don't need Crystal Designer. They need Crystal Runtime for .NET framework, which has separate installs (one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit).

Comment: Thanks. There are many links in the web. Can u suggest me the official link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good official resource: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads